# Azure Maps API does not return results for existing geographic entities

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Did anyone experience problems trying to locate specific cities / municipalities or in general geographic entities using the Azure Maps Fuzzy API? In most cases the API works just fine, however I discovered some few cases, where the API simply doesn't return any results. For instance I don't get any results for the city of [Shenzhen (China)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhen).

I tried different combinations of query parameters, such as:

```
query:         Shenzhen
countrySet:    CHN
minFuzzyLevel: 4
maxFuzzyLevel: 4
limit:         10
idxSet:        Geo
```

But the API just returns an empty result. Am I missing some magic parameter? The problem is not restricted to China and I can provide more examples if necessary.

**Further examples**

[Freeport (Bahamas)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeport,_Bahamas)

```
query:         Freeport
countrySet:    BHS
minFuzzyLevel: 4
maxFuzzyLevel: 4
limit:         10
idxSet:        Geo
```

[Caucedo (Costa Rica)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_Caucedo)

```
query:         Caucedo
countrySet:    CRI
minFuzzyLevel: 4
maxFuzzyLevel: 4
limit:         10
idxSet:        Geo
```

[Yokohama (Japan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yokohama)

```
query:         Yokohama
countrySet:    JPN
minFuzzyLevel: 4
maxFuzzyLevel: 4
limit:         10
idxSet:        Geo
```

[Sihanoukville (Cambodia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sihanoukville_(city))

```
query:         Sihanoukville
countrySet:    KHM
minFuzzyLevel: 4
maxFuzzyLevel: 4
limit:         10
idxSet:        Geo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

China is not currently supported as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/about-azure-maps#supported-regions

The team is working on adding support.

Comment: i think this refers to the availability of the service itself, but not the ability to process requests regarding geographic entities located in China. i'm not accessing the API from a Chinese IP

Comment: Its the same issue. Detailed data of China is not currently supported in Azure Maps.

Comment: could you have a look at the new examples I added to my original question? they do not relate to the territory of china, but still don't provide any results.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I see the issue. The fuzzy search API prioritizes for address level data and POI's. For cities, I recommend using the Address search or Structured Address search API. Those will be more accurate. Also take a look at the best practices guide for search here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-best-practices-for-search

Comment: unfortunately adding `Addr`,`PAD` or `Str` did not yield relevant results if any

Comment: I'll have our data provider take a look to see if there are any issues with the service.

Comment: do you have any news regarding potential issues with the service?

Comment: Our data provider is working on correcting this issue.